# Prevent show push notification using iOS Notification Service Extensions

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-extensions, notificationservices

I know that with the iOS Notification Service Extensions it is possibile pre-process the push notifications.
I'm searching for a procedure that allow me to skip the push notification is a condition is verified. 
For example if the push is not updated anymore I want avoid to disturb the user.

Is it possible with Notification Service Extensions, or other? I've already tried setting the body to empty string but the modify is discarded.

Thanks

Comment: Did you able to prevent it?

Comment: No it is impossible by design.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a notification via the Notification Service Extension, you must present a notification to the user. You cannot cancel/skip it. The best you can do is setting `notificationContent.sound = nil`,  which will silence the notification, while still presenting the banner.

Another option is to use Silent Push Notifications, so you can pre-process it and decide wether you want to show a notification or not: then use [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) to present a local notification.